# Dropping L in compound adjectives. Is it "skillful" or "skilful"?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage, north-american-english, doubled-consonants, commonweath-english

We have been taught at school that when a word ending in "LL" helps form a compound word, "LL" becomes "L" (e.g. skill -> skilful). I have also come across the usage of this adjective as *skillful* (with double L's). I checked the NGram to see how the usage has changed over time, and it got me more confused:

[image: Ngram of skillfull vs skilful]

What is the correct form of *skilful* and similar words? Is there a definite rule or are both usages acceptable?

Comment: Your graphs include 2 new terms which are ending with *fuLL*. I don't think it's correct.

Comment: ...actually, now I'm confused. You haven't actually given a link to your NGram, and I can barely make out the precise letters of the two spellings, but if you really did have *skillful* I don't know what went wrong. British English used to be vague on this one, and both *skilfull* and *skilful* did occur, but we've pretty much fallen into line with American *skillful* now. My "British" Google Chrome keeps telling me I should be using **skilful**, but this is one case where I just know it's antiquated and wrong.

Comment: ...the standard version everywhere these days is **skillful**

Comment: My NGram link: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skillful%2Cskilful&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: oic - my confusion came about because I simply couldn't read the two choices. Gnawme is right, but I have to say this is one case where I disown my countrymen's spelling - I've always preferred **skillful**, and it seems likely to me everyone else will fall into line soon enough!

Comment: I may fall into that line soon, as well. :)

Comment: The same happens with **willful** (which again my Anglicised Chrome says should be **wilful**). Personally, I think I've already cut such words down to size by dropping the doubled L at the end. To go hacking out one of those in the middle as well seems excessive to me. I don't weep for the letters lost in **dialog**, or even **thru**, but there are limits!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's largely an [American vs British spelling](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/british-american-spelling.html) difference, with Americans preferring *[skillful](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/skillful)*.

(Note that the British version of Macmillan says *skillful* is the "American spelling of [*skilful*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/skillful).")

Comment: Google nGrams suggests *skillful* only fell behind *skilful* in American English [since about 1925](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skillful%2Cskilful&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

As Gnawme states, "skillful" is an American English spelling. However, "skilful" is not necessarily just [British English :](http://grammarist.com/spelling/skilful-skillful/)

> For the adjective meaning "with skill or having skill", "skillful" is the preferred spelling in American English. "Skilful" is  preferred in all other varieties of English.

Comment: Your "British English" link cites three example non-US usages, one of which is Britain's Daily Mail. But it's somewhat undermined by the fact that when I went there and searched the MailOnline website for **skillful**, it produced me [5 pages, at 50 results per page](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/search.html?sel=site&searchPhrase=skillful). Admittedly, there are 50 pages for **skilful**, but it certainly goes to show the Daily Mail doesn't feel strongly enough about it to enforce consistency - which they could easily do if they cared at all.

Comment: ...much the same ratio occurs in [The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/search?q=skillful&target=guardian), and in both cases I would expect the proportion of "US spellings" to rise noticeably every year.